Cache eviction doesn't work when using ConcurrentMapCache with sync = true in a multithreaded environment
If I use ConcurrentMapCache in CacheManager and @Cacheable with sync = true, and multiple threads are calling the cache enabled method for 60 seconds or more for the given CacheConfiguration then the cache is never getting updated with new value.
CacheConfiguration
  @Bean
  @Override
  public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    SimpleCacheManager cacheManager = new SimpleCacheManager();
    cacheManager.setCaches(
        Set.of(
            new ConcurrentMapCache(
                "myCache",
                CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                    .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build()
                    .asMap(),
                false)));
    return cacheManager;
  }

**Service: **
  @Cacheable(cacheNames = "myCache", sync = true)
  public String getValue(String id){
    return sampleString.getNewValue(id);
  }

Although, if I change the underlying cache to CaffeineCache in CacheManager then it works fine.
Could somebody explain the reason behind the ConcurrentMapCache having issue with sync?
I change the underlying cache to CaffeineCache in CacheManager then it works fine.

ConcurrentMapCache uses Java 8's compute methods and Guava's Cache predated them. They later tried to retrofitted them on but it does that by locking the entire cache segment instead of the entry. This makes it very slow and, iirc, there were deadlock bugs making it relatively undesirable. CacheBuilder recommends using Caffeine instead, fwiw.
